# Office Web App - Show task pane on load

Tags: ms-office, office-js

How do I show a custom taskpane automatically when the add-in loads (i.e. without having to click a command that is tied to that URL)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Jan 2018 update:**

Office has shipped a new feature which lets you configure your add-in to automatically open a task pane when the file loads if the add-in had been used there previously: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document.

**Original Answer:**

<s>Commands cannot currently be used to launch a task pane when the document opens.</s> 
However, you can cause the task pane to open automatically if you remove all commands from the manifest entirely.