# Keep Office add-in task pane open at document load

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-js

I have a task pane (desktop) Office add-in built with the latest VS 2015 template for Excel and Word add-ins. When I open the file, the add-in task pane is not visible. My users need to click a button on the toolbar to open it, which they complain about.

In addition, I save the document with the task pane expanded but it does not affect that behavior. I remember a previous version of the add-in manifest (when it was called app for Office) kept the pane open but I upgraded it so I can use custom tabs in the Office ribbon.

Can I make the task pane stay expanded when the document or worksheet load?

Comment: Try this Auto opening task pane:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488042/7487988](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488042/7487988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a way to do this: [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document). And a sample at: [Office OOXML EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin)

Answer (score 1):

Similar question here: [Office Web App - Show task pane on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359620/office-web-app-show-task-pane-on-load/39376680#39376680)

For now you'll have to choose between persistent always-open task panes and custom tabs/buttons.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Will this be part of the Office add-in road-map?