# OfficeJs addin Keep task pane open all the time when new document is created or opened

Tags: macos, ms-word, office365, office-js

I want to keep task pane open all the time when new document is created or opened for office mac word addin, when ever user open or create new document it should show the add-in task pane.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate question check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379427/keep-office-add-in-task-pane-open-at-document-load

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario requires doing this for any document I don't think you can do that, at least not yet.