# Unable to load deployed add-ins automatically in Office 365

Tags: office365

I have created a customized add-in to MS word and I deployed that through Centralized Deployment via the Office 365 admin center.

I want this add-in to be loaded automatically when users enter Word online.

But currently I am not able to load it automatically.

Is there a way to automatically load my add-in in Word Online without the intervention of the user?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to keep Office add-in task pane open when the document load in word online.

So please follow the steps in the following link to automatically open a task pane:

[Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document)

For more information, please have a look:

[Keep Office add-in task pane open at document load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379427/keep-office-add-in-task-pane-open-at-document-load)

Comment: It is not about the task pane. Add-in itself is not loading when users open the document, and they have to insert the add-ins manually. I want add-ins automatically visible to the users.