# Auto-opening side-loaded taskpane

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

Is it possible to auto-open plugins that are in developer mode?

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document)

> The pane that you designate to open automatically **will only open if
>   the add-in is already installed on the user's device**. If the user does
>   not have the add-in installed when they open a document, the autoopen
>   feature will not work and the setting will be ignored. If you also
>   require the add-in to be distributed with the document you need to set
>   the visibility property to 1; this can only be done using OpenXML, an
>   example is provided later in this article.

In particular, the file i'm attempting to auto-open is what based off [office-generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office) with a single modification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <we:webextension xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" id="{acbc717b-5139-428a-9089-e9d6d7d8affc}">
  <we:reference id="acbc717b-5139-428a-9089-e9d6d7d8affc" version="1.0.0.0" store="developer" storeType="Registry"/>
  <we:alternateReferences/>

  <we:properties>
    <we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true"/>
  </we:properties>

  <we:bindings/>
  <we:snapshot xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"/>
</we:webextension>
```

with the addition of `<we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true"/>`

and by modifying `manifest.xml` as follows:

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
  <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
  <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
</Action>
```

**Problem:**

It is expected that there would be one taskpane which would be opened automatically.

The task pane that was opened automatically has an error which states that `we can't find the task pane to open`. On the other hand, clicking on the ribbon allows the task pane to open as per normal, side by side with the broken auto-opened task pane as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Please use the Fiddler tool to compare HTTP Request/Response when the pane autoopens and when you press the button.

Comment: @RickKirkham [Seems to be attempting to connect to office instead of localhost.](https://imgur.com/h2QsEtU).

After the arrow is when i click the button to open the second taskpane.

Comment: @RickKirkham

More specifically, it only attempts to connect to:

`GET /ocs/docs/recent?rs=en-US&apps=Word&show=100 HTTP/1.1`, then 
`GET /ocs/locations/recent?rs=en-US&apps=Word&show=100 HTTP/1.1`

and eventually `POST /rs/RoamingSoapService.svc HTTP/1.1`.

It never attempts to hit localhost until i open the other taskpane.

Comment: @RickKirkham

I have tried to implement Auto Open TaskPane feature with Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true) and saving this settings. but TaskPane is getting auto open for newly created documents only. For Older documents which are already present in a system(might be created maximum before a month), or them Task Pane is not getting auto open.

Comment: Although attempts were made using the mentioned approach and injecting task pane information through OpenXML, they did not yield the desired results. Are there any alternative methods available for achieving this functionality?

The Regarding auto-opening the task pane without saving the document or opening the document with the same task pane is already documented by Microsoft.
Also when we inject through the openxml it is also injecting the version so if version changed in manifest it should not work.
Let me know if you find any other alternative for same.

Answer (score 3):

There's a hidden-state in Microsoft Word somewhere, that persists even after restarts. To reproduce the error you pretty much need a **new computer**.

Let me explain how i got it working after... 1 week.

First start with office-js generator.

`yo office`, for which i selected typescript.

[image]

Modify src/taskpane/taskpane.ts as follows:

```
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async context => {
    /**
     * Insert your Word code here
     */

    // insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
    const paragraph = context.document.body.insertParagraph("Hello World", Word.InsertLocation.end);

    // change the paragraph color to blue.
    paragraph.font.color = "blue";

    // Add these two lines
    Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
    // Technically should wait, but doesn't matter.

    await context.sync();
  });
```

Modify manifest.xml as follows:
Replace `ButtonId1` with `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument`

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
  <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
  <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
</Action>
```

Launch the project as per normal.
`npm run start`

Click the run button to trigger the creation of the auto-open file.

[image]

Save the file somewhere.

Re-open it to verify that it works. Funnily enough, it created an identical taskpanes when i clicked on the show taskpane button. This is a bug but works for me. It's for testing purposes after all.

[image]

To prove that the file's problem is indeed a hidden state:
Clone the repo on a **new computer**, `npm run start`, copy the file over.

Run the file and you will get the same problem as i got in my original post.

Comment: Thank you... The post is useful... Do you know if it is possible to test autoopen in localhost?

Comment: The provided information regarding auto-opening the task pane without saving the document or opening the document with the same task pane is already documented by Microsoft. The question pertains to whether the task pane should automatically open without requiring the document to be saved, or if it should open when the document is opened with the same task pane.

Although attempts were made using the mentioned approach and injecting task pane information through OpenXML, they did not yield the desired results. Are there any alternative methods available for achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

After extensive investigation over the past 2-3 days, I've identified a potential solution to the issue. It appears that synchronization between the manifest file and the webextension XML information is crucial.

To ensure proper functionality, please follow these steps to verify the document and webextension XML:

**1) Manfiest.xml**

```
         <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
            <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
            <!--Provide
            a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane -->
            <SourceLocation resid="Aavenir.Taskpane1.Url" />
          </Action>
```

**2) webextension.xml (part of document)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><we:webextension xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" id="{31fe9903-efb9-4f54-aeca-b361bcf10fe0}"><we:reference id="8e29c697-73cb-456f-b9e3-4857bbcabbaa" version="1.0.0.0" store="EXCatalog" storeType="EXCatalog" /><we:properties><we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true" /></we:properties><we:bindings /><we:snapshot xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" /></we:webextension>
```

3. Using office JS :
   If you aim to inject the task pane upon opening the document and perform operations using your task pane:

   Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
   Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();

Implementing these steps should address the issue and ensure proper functionality of the task pane. Please verify and let me know if any further assistance is needed.

Thanks,

Hardik Shah

Happy coding!